# keylistener and JMenuBar issue

Tags: java, swing, bluej, jmenubar

The menu bar won't draw and the keylistener won't work. Should I add the menu bar to a panel or a content pane? What am I doing wrong? What to do? Help? Thank you!

**Please copy and run the code first.**

**CLASS DRAWINGDEMO**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrawingDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
DrawingPanel demo = new DrawingPanel();
public DrawingDemo()
{

getContentPane().add(demo);
setVisible(true);
setSize(1024,720);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JPanel p = new JPanel();
JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
JMenu settings = new JMenu("Settings");
JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem(">Exit");
JMenuItem imp = new JMenuItem(">Import");
JMenuItem exp = new JMenuItem(">Export");
JMenuItem sav = new JMenuItem(">Save");
JMenuItem ope = new JMenuItem(">Open");
file.add(ope);  
file.add(sav);
file.add(imp);
file.add(exp);
file.add(exit);
mb.add(file);
mb.add(edit);
mb.add(settings);
mb.add(help);
setJMenuBar(mb);

while(true){
 demo.repaint();
}
}
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
{
}
public void KeyEvent(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
{
}
public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e)
{
}
public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e)
 {
 switch (e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_A : 
    {
    demo.pos_camx -= 0.5;
    }
    break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D :
    {
    demo.pos_camx += 0.5;
    }
    break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_W :
    {
    demo.pos_camy += 0.5;
    }
    break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S :
    {
    demo.pos_camy -= 0.5;
    }
    break;
    } 
}
public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e)
{
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new DrawingDemo();
}
}
```

**CLASS DRAWINGPANEL**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

long nextSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
int framesInLastSecond = 0;
int framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
int[][] LP= new int[19][3];
  double pos_camx,pos_camy,pos_camz,rot_camx,rot_camy,xpoint,ypoint,zpoint;
  double rot_radx,rot_rady,nclip,xscr,yscr,kx,ky;
  int pxscr,pyscr,nxscr,nyscr,e;



 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
            LP[0][0] = -1;
        LP[0][1] = -1;
        LP[0][2] = -1;

        LP[1][0] = 1;
        LP[1][1] = -1;
        LP[1][2] = -1;

        LP[2][0] = 1;
        LP[2][1] = 1;
        LP[2][2] = -1;

        LP[3][0] = -1;
        LP[3][1] = 1;
        LP[3][2] = -1;

        LP[4][0] = -1;
        LP[4][1] = -1;
        LP[4][2] = -1;

        LP[5][0] = 1;
        LP[5][1] = 1;
        LP[5][2] = -1;

        LP[6][0] = 1;
        LP[6][1] = 1;
        LP[6][2] = 1;

        LP[7][0] = -1;
        LP[7][1] = 1;
        LP[7][2] = 1;

        LP[8][0] = -1;
        LP[8][1] = -1;
        LP[8][2] = 1;

        LP[9][0] = 1;
        LP[9][1] = -1;
        LP[9][2] = 1;

        LP[10][0] = 1;
        LP[10][1] = 1;
        LP[10][2] = 1;

        LP[11][0] = -1;
        LP[11][1] = -1;
        LP[11][2] = 1;

        LP[12][0] = -1;
        LP[12][1] = -1;
        LP[12][2] = -1;

        LP[13][0] = 1;
        LP[13][1] = -1;
        LP[13][2] = 1;

        LP[14][0] = 1;
        LP[14][1] = -1;
        LP[14][2] = -1;

        LP[15][0] = 1;
        LP[15][1] = 1;
        LP[15][2] = 1;

        LP[16][0] = -1;
        LP[16][1] = 1;
        LP[16][2] = -1;

        LP[17][0] = -1;
        LP[17][1] = 1;
        LP[17][2] = 1;

        LP[18][0] = -1;
        LP[18][1] = -1;
        LP[18][2] = -1; 

 pos_camx = 0;
 pos_camy = 0;
 pos_camz = 0;

 rot_camx = 0;
 rot_camy = 0;
 rot_radx = 3.1415*rot_camx/180;
 rot_rady = 3.1415*rot_camy/180;

 nclip = 0.275;
 kx = 8.52/getWidth();
 ky = 5.46/getHeight();
 super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g1.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,   RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
     xpoint = (double)(LP[0][0])/2;
     ypoint = 20 + (double)(LP[0][1])/2;
     zpoint = (double)(LP[0][2])/2;

     pxscr = (int)(
     ((xpoint - pos_camx)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_radx))*nclip
     /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx- xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012)*100/kx
                  + getWidth()/2);

     pyscr = (int)(
                  getHeight()/2-
     (((ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_rady) + (zpoint - pos_camz)*Math.cos(rot_rady))*nclip
     /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx + xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012)*100/ky)
                  );
     for (int i=1; i<19;i++){
            xpoint = (double)(LP[i][0])/2;
            ypoint = 20 + (double)(LP[i][1])/2;
            zpoint = (double)(LP[i][2])/2;

            nxscr = (int)(
         ((xpoint - pos_camx)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_radx))*nclip
         /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx)+(pos_camx + xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx)+0.0000000012)*100/kx
                         +getWidth()/2);

            nyscr = (int)(
                         getHeight()/2-
         (((ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_rady)+(zpoint - pos_camz)*Math.cos(rot_rady))*nclip
         /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx)+(pos_camx + xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx)+0.0000000012)*100/ky)
                         );
            g1.drawLine(pxscr,pyscr,nxscr,nyscr);

         pxscr = nxscr;
         pyscr = nyscr;
        }
         g.drawString("(" + pxscr + "," + pyscr + ")",20,40);
         long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if (currentTime > nextSecond) {
    nextSecond += 1000;
    framesInLastSecond = framesInCurrentSecond;
    framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
  }
 framesInCurrentSecond++;
 g.drawString(framesInLastSecond + " fps", 20, 20);
}

}
```

Comment: `while (true) { demo.repaint(); }` here's your first problem

Comment: You''l never exit the constructor, from this infinite loop.

Comment: 1) `public void paint(Graphics g)` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` for a Swing `JPanel` 2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: The logic in that code is nonsense.  For example, what is the point of incrementing `pos_camx` in the main class, but setting the value again in `paint(..)`?  I might be able to fix this code if it was obvious what should happen.
  Some of the problems though.  1) Use Key Bindings rather than `KeyListener` 2) If using `KeyListener` ensure it is added to the correct component, and that component is focusable (it wasn't & was not). 3) Don't extend `JFrame` simply use an instance. ..  I suggest you throw this code away and start again at the tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Swing is an Event Driven environment, blocking the Event Dispatching Thread in any way will prevent it from begin able to process any events (such as mouse or keyboard events).

`KeyListener` is a low level API and is generally discourage for a number of reasons, focus issues been the most prominent.  In order for a component to be able to respond to a `KeyListener` it must be focusable and have focus.  The problem you have, is neither of these conditions are actually being meet (nor are you actually registering the key listener with anything).

While the `JFrame` is focusable, it contains a `JRootPane` which contains (amongst other things) a content pane, which contains your `DrawingPanel`.  Any of these may steal focus from the frame at any time, rendering your `KeyListener` useless.

The preferred method is to use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Generally, you are discouraged from overriding `paint`.  Paint is a very complex method and you should only override it if you are absolutely sure it is the right thing to do.  The preferred method for performing custom painting is to override the `paintComponent` method, as out lined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).  The most important reason for this, is this method is double buffered, making you painting smoother, also, you, generally, won't interfere with other components that may be on the component.

Also, in your paint method, you are setting the camera positions to `0` which basically undoes all you good work with your non-functional key listeners ;)

```
public class DrawingDemo extends JFrame { //implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    DrawingPanel demo = new DrawingPanel();

    public DrawingDemo() {

        getContentPane().add(demo);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1024, 720);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu settings = new JMenu("Settings");
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem(">Exit");
        JMenuItem imp = new JMenuItem(">Import");
        JMenuItem exp = new JMenuItem(">Export");
        JMenuItem sav = new JMenuItem(">Save");
        JMenuItem ope = new JMenuItem(">Open");
        file.add(ope);
        file.add(sav);
        file.add(imp);
        file.add(exp);
        file.add(exit);
        mb.add(file);
        mb.add(edit);
        mb.add(settings);
        mb.add(help);
        setJMenuBar(mb);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawingDemo();
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        long nextSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
        int framesInLastSecond = 0;
        int framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
        int[][] LP = new int[19][3];
        double pos_camx, pos_camy, pos_camz, rot_camx, rot_camy, xpoint, ypoint, zpoint;
        double rot_radx, rot_rady, nclip, xscr, yscr, kx, ky;
        int pxscr, pyscr, nxscr, nyscr, e;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "Move.A");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "Move.D");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "Move.W");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "Move.S");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("Move.A", new MoveXAction(this, 0.5f));
            am.put("Move.D", new MoveXAction(this, -0.5f));
            am.put("Move.W", new MoveYAction(this, 0.5f));
            am.put("Move.S", new MoveYAction(this, -0.5f));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

            LP[0][0] = -1;
            LP[0][1] = -1;
            LP[0][2] = -1;

            LP[1][0] = 1;
            LP[1][1] = -1;
            LP[1][2] = -1;

            LP[2][0] = 1;
            LP[2][1] = 1;
            LP[2][2] = -1;

            LP[3][0] = -1;
            LP[3][1] = 1;
            LP[3][2] = -1;

            LP[4][0] = -1;
            LP[4][1] = -1;
            LP[4][2] = -1;

            LP[5][0] = 1;
            LP[5][1] = 1;
            LP[5][2] = -1;

            LP[6][0] = 1;
            LP[6][1] = 1;
            LP[6][2] = 1;

            LP[7][0] = -1;
            LP[7][1] = 1;
            LP[7][2] = 1;

            LP[8][0] = -1;
            LP[8][1] = -1;
            LP[8][2] = 1;

            LP[9][0] = 1;
            LP[9][1] = -1;
            LP[9][2] = 1;

            LP[10][0] = 1;
            LP[10][1] = 1;
            LP[10][2] = 1;

            LP[11][0] = -1;
            LP[11][1] = -1;
            LP[11][2] = 1;

            LP[12][0] = -1;
            LP[12][1] = -1;
            LP[12][2] = -1;

            LP[13][0] = 1;
            LP[13][1] = -1;
            LP[13][2] = 1;

            LP[14][0] = 1;
            LP[14][1] = -1;
            LP[14][2] = -1;

            LP[15][0] = 1;
            LP[15][1] = 1;
            LP[15][2] = 1;

            LP[16][0] = -1;
            LP[16][1] = 1;
            LP[16][2] = -1;

            LP[17][0] = -1;
            LP[17][1] = 1;
            LP[17][2] = 1;

            LP[18][0] = -1;
            LP[18][1] = -1;
            LP[18][2] = -1;

//            pos_camx = 0;
//            pos_camy = 0;
//            pos_camz = 0;

            rot_camx = 0;
            rot_camy = 0;
            rot_radx = 3.1415 * rot_camx / 180;
            rot_rady = 3.1415 * rot_camy / 180;

            nclip = 0.275;
            kx = 8.52 / getWidth();
            ky = 5.46 / getHeight();
            Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g1.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            xpoint = (double) (LP[0][0]) / 2;
            ypoint = 20 + (double) (LP[0][1]) / 2;
            zpoint = (double) (LP[0][2]) / 2;

            pxscr = (int) (((xpoint - pos_camx) * Math.cos(rot_radx) + (ypoint + pos_camy) * Math.sin(rot_radx)) * nclip
                    / ((ypoint - pos_camy) * Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx - xpoint) * Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012) * 100 / kx
                    + getWidth() / 2);

            pyscr = (int) (getHeight() / 2
                    - (((ypoint + pos_camy) * Math.sin(rot_rady) + (zpoint - pos_camz) * Math.cos(rot_rady)) * nclip
                    / ((ypoint - pos_camy) * Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx + xpoint) * Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012) * 100 / ky));
            for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
                xpoint = (double) (LP[i][0]) / 2;
                ypoint = 20 + (double) (LP[i][1]) / 2;
                zpoint = (double) (LP[i][2]) / 2;

                nxscr = (int) (((xpoint - pos_camx) * Math.cos(rot_radx) + (ypoint + pos_camy) * Math.sin(rot_radx)) * nclip
                        / ((ypoint - pos_camy) * Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx + xpoint) * Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012) * 100 / kx
                        + getWidth() / 2);

                nyscr = (int) (getHeight() / 2
                        - (((ypoint + pos_camy) * Math.sin(rot_rady) + (zpoint - pos_camz) * Math.cos(rot_rady)) * nclip
                        / ((ypoint - pos_camy) * Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx + xpoint) * Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012) * 100 / ky));
                g1.drawLine(pxscr, pyscr, nxscr, nyscr);

                pxscr = nxscr;
                pyscr = nyscr;
            }
            g.drawString("(" + pxscr + "," + pyscr + ")", 20, 40);
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime > nextSecond) {
                nextSecond += 1000;
                framesInLastSecond = framesInCurrentSecond;
                framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
            }
            framesInCurrentSecond++;
            g.drawString(framesInLastSecond + " fps", 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public class MoveXAction extends AbstractAction {

        private float direction;
        private final DrawingPanel pane;

        private MoveXAction(DrawingPanel pane, float amount) {

            this.direction = amount;
            this.pane = pane;

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("...x by " + direction);
            pane.pos_camx += direction;
            pane.repaint();
        }

    }

    public class MoveYAction extends AbstractAction {

        private float direction;
        private final DrawingPanel pane;

        private MoveYAction(DrawingPanel pane, float amount) {

            this.direction = amount;
            this.pane = pane;

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("...y by " + direction);
            pane.pos_camy += direction;
            pane.repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

I had a quick play around and I have to say, Nice ;)

Comment: +1 very nice and for advies on KeyBindings, and looking ate the code its a camera rotation on JPanel?? Truelly awesome by OP

Answer (score 0):

you only need to repaint if something changed, and even then, probably not a million times a second ( or whatever your cpu can handle). so i would suggest to change the `while(true)` to a loop which waits for a bit, or repaint in the keylistener (depending on what you want the application to do)

and you implement the `keylistener` interface, but you are not adding it to the registered listeners so you need a `this.addKeyListener(this);`

the `JMenuBar` doesnt show up because you make the frame visible before adding the menubar. normally you want to make the window visible after initializing its components.
so put the `setVisible(true);` after you add the menubar

Comment: Actually, the menu bar doesn't show up because he's blocking the EDT, your point is valid one. Had he added the menu before calling `setVisible` it's possible that the menu bar would have shown up ;)